# Requests don't run on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is, that when the page is loaded(document.ready), these ajax requests doesnt do anything, and i dont get any error in the console.

I alerted the selectedAtvetel to check the value of it, but thats correct always.

The `$('#atvetel_select').val();` is a checkbox, and if i get some error from the php file when submitting the form, the page reloads and it select keeps the selected option, so i get the selectedAtvetel from there at page reload, not just at onchange.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var selectedAtvetel = $('#atvetel_select').val();
    alert(selectedAtvetel);
    if(selectedAtvetel != 0 )
    {
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'files/get_payment_mods.php',
             data: { szallitas_id: selectedAtvetel },
             dataType: "html",
             cache: false,
             beforeSend: function(){
                $('#preloader_atvetel').show();
             },
             success: function(data){
                 var result = $.trim(data);
                 $('#payment_mods').html(result);
             },
             complete: function(){
                $('#preloader_atvetel').hide();
             }
        });

        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'files/megrendeles_totals.php',
             data: { id: selectedAtvetel },
             dataType: "html",
             cache: false,
             success: function(data){
                 var result = $.trim(data);
                 $('.totalAmountArea').html(result);
             }
        });

        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'files/get_atvetel_text.php',
             data: { id: selectedAtvetel },
             dataType: "html",
             cache: false,
             beforeSend: function(){
                $('#preloader_atvetel').show();
             },
             success: function(data){
                 var result = $.trim(data);
                 $('#atvetel_result').html(result);
             },
             complete: function(){
                $('#preloader_atvetel').hide();
             }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't the issue, but (FYI), `selectedAtvetel != 0` should really be `selectedAtvetel != "0"` since the `val()` will always return a string. You get away with it here because you are using `!=` (compare with conversion), but it wouldn't work with `!==` (strict comparison - no conversion).

Comment: Have you tried this with the Network tab of the Developer's Tools open? This tab will conclusively tell you if the request is being made.

Comment: You should really post the corresponding HTML as well so we can have an executable version of your code to work with and we can replicate your issue.

Comment: If you do this at document load, the user hasn't had a chance to fill in inputs, check checkboxes, etc. What's the point of getting the values?

Comment: I only want to do this, when he filled the inputs, but he maybe entered a wrong captcha. So then, the php will echo out an error and reload the page, but the option will be keeped checked, so i can get the value of it. Thats why i alert it first, to check the value, and thats working right.

Comment: I removed it from the document ready, and replaced the selectedAtvetel != 0 to selectedAtvetel != "0", or selectedAtvetel !== 0, but notrhing, its still does nothing, only the alert works right with the right value.